# correct use of being and having

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which one is correct....

1) Being revived the man was asked for something to drink.

2) Having revived the man was asked for something to drink.

Comment: After the man came to, did he ask for something to drink? Your examples both imply that someone requested a drink _from the revived man_. Otherwise, "After he was revived, the man asked for something to drink."

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of usage.

"Having revived..." is the condition of the subject reviving. The reference is to the subject reviving.

"Being revived..." is the condition of the subject having been revived. The reference is to someone else reviving the subject.